# ArrayList as global variable

Tags: java, android

I created class that extend of application like that

```
package com.appnetics;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Application;

public class GlobalVariables extends Application {

    public ArrayList<Encounter> encounters;

}
```

and set it in manifist like this

```
<application
android:name="GlobalVariables"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

in one Actiity I fill this array using this code

```
GlobalVariables appState = new GlobalVariables();
appState.encounters =new ArrayList<Encounter>(); 
................
then add
```

when trying to use it  it crash with null exception, I use it in another activity or class like that

```
    GlobalVariables appState = new GlobalVariables();

    Encounter EncounterObject = appState.encounters.get(position);
```

is there something missing please , how to fix that

Comment: You are creating a new instance of GlobalVariabels each time. So when you are trying to get your list get(position) will be null

Answer (score 4):

It's an *instance* variable of the `GlobalVariables` class, so every time you create a new *instance* of `GlobalVariables`, you'll get a separate variable.

If you *really* want a global variable, it should be a *static* variable - but even that will only work if you're sharing data between activities in the same process. You should read the [Android Application Framework FAQ](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the Singleton pattern here. [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

```
public class GlobalVariables {
  public ArrayList<Encounter> encounters;

  private GlobalVariables() {
    encounters = new ArrayList<Encounter>();
  }

  private static GlobalVariables instance;

  public static GlobalVariables getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) instance = new GlobalVariables();
    return instance;
  }
}
```

And then you can access your data by using:

```
GlobalVariables.getInstance().encounters.get(position);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make singleton ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern]) class that provide one instance of object. And create ArrayList veriable in this class. And the you can access this arraylist where you want.
For example singleton class:

```
public class Singleton {

private ArrayList<Object> arrayList;

private static Singleton instance;

private Singleton(){
    arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();
}

public static Singleton getInstance(){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return instance;
}

public ArrayList<Object> getArrayList() {
    return arrayList;
}
}
```

And using in activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Singleton.getInstance().getArrayList();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are Creating a new application object by calling constructor each time, instead you should get Application Reference, by method, getApplication(). So you should edit your code to:

```
GlobalVariables appState = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();
appState.encounters =new ArrayList<Encounter>(); 
................
then add
```

and

```
GlobalVariables appState = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();

Encounter EncounterObject = appState.encounters.get(position);
```

Comment: ok, but I need to call it in class extend from extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> how to getApplication()

Comment: To call it into Class Extending AsyncTask you need to pass Application or Activity Reference to the AsyncTask.

Comment: which call the asyncktask is extend from fragment
so I only have context