# Declraring a global arrayList in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How do I declare a Global ArrayList accesible from all methods. I tried to declare it in main,in class, and various other places.

```
 public static void InitializeTrips() {
        public static List<Trip> TripList = new ArrayList<>();
        TripList.add(new Trip(1, "NGP", "MUM", 3000, 1200, 1330));
        TripList.add(new Trip(1, "MUM", "NGP", 3500, 1400, 1530));
    }
public static void AddTrips() {
        Scanner inpt = new Scanner(System.in);
        int trpindx;String str;String end;int cst;int tmes;int tmee;
        System.out.println("Please input the following :-");
        System.out.print("Trip Index : "); trpindx = inpt.nextInt(); ;System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Source     : "); str = inpt.next(); ;System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("End        : "); end = inpt.next(); ;System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Cost       : "); cst = inpt.nextInt(); ;System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Departure  : "); tmes = inpt.nextInt(); ;System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Arrival    : "); tmee = inpt.nextInt(); ;System.out.println("");

}

public  static  void PrintTrips() {
    System.out.print("Index     Source     Destination     Depature     Arrival     Cost    ");
    .TripList.forEach(TripList -> {
        System.out.println( ( TripList.getTRPINDX() )+ "     " +(TripList.getSTR)+"     "+(TripList.getEND)+"     "+(TripList.getCST)+"     "+(TripList.getTMEs)+"     "+(TripList.getTMEe)+"     "+(TripList.getDUR)+");
    });
```

Comment: pls check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976212/arraylist-as-global-variable

Comment: Hey, isnt that for android,Also i dont understan how to implement that in Idealj

Comment: create a singleton class which will return ArrayList  object, please check above link

Comment: Thank you, I will implement and tell back

Comment: Hey I am still not unable to impement it.Can u help me out :-https://pastebin.com/1Pkd7AFL

Comment: please check sample code, let's try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this sample code:-

```
package design.pattern;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GlobalAccessVariables {
      public ArrayList<Trip> trips;

      private GlobalAccessVariables() {
        trips = new ArrayList<Trip>();
      }

      private static GlobalAccessVariables instance;

      public static GlobalAccessVariables getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) 
            instance = new GlobalAccessVariables();
        return instance;
      }

}
```

for access it in any class :

```
GlobalAccessVariables instance = GlobalAccessVariables.getInstance();
ArrayList tripsList = instance.trips;
tripsList.add("add trip here")
```

hope it will work for you

Comment: Thanks for you solution. There is error it is not working for get_functions created i created : -https://pastebin.com/p6kuhgBH

Comment: function name ?

Comment: All the get functions, new paste :-https://pastebin.com/7ThnzyKt, I am using idea intellij the code is showing error.

Comment: public  static  void PrintTrips() {
        GlobalAccessVariables instance = GlobalAccessVariables.getInstance();
        ArrayList tripList = instance.TripList ;
        System.out.print("Index     Source     Destination     Depature     Arrival     Cost    ");
        Iterator iterator = tripList.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
         Trip next =(Trip)iterator.next();
         System.out.print( next.getTRPINDX() +""+next.getSTR()+""+next.getEND()+""+next.getTMEe()+""+next.getTMEs());
        }
   }

Comment: above method is modified only and rest coding is working fine